# Add product on order through admin doesn't work. Magento 2 fresh install

Tags: magento2

When I create a new order and I want to add some products it looks like he is adding it. It shows a loader but when it's done nothing is added. I also have it on my normal webshop but I though let's try a fresh install of magento 2.2.4.

The same issue. How weird!

[image]

[image]